# Unary - operator overloading using friend function

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have written this code in an attempt to perform overloading on the unary operator - using a friend function. Somehow, there is no effect on the inital values I've passed.

```
#include<iostream>
//fifty6s
using namespace std;
class invert_position
{
    int x,y;
    public:
        invert_position(int a,int b)
        {
        x=a;
        y=b;
        }
    void show()
        {
            cout<<"\nx="<<x;
            cout<<"\ny="<<y;
        }
    friend void operator -(invert_position);
};
void operator -(invert_position i)
{
    i.x=-i.x;
    i.y=-i.y;
}
int main()
{
    invert_position i(2,3);
    -i;
    i.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does it do when you write `i = -i;` instead if `-i;`?

Comment: It works that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues that I see in your posted code.

1. The `operator-` function needs to return an `invert_position` object. Otherwise,

   ```
   invert_position i(2,3);
   invert_position j = -i;
   ```

   is a problem. Think of it similarly to using a fundamental type.

   ```
   int i = 10;
   int j = -i;  // We expect j to be -10 after this.
   ```

   Hence, what yo need is

   ```
   invert_position  operator -(invert_position i)
   {
       i.x=-i.x;
       i.y=-i.y;
       return i;
   }
   ```
2. The line

   ```
   -i;
   ```

   does not change the value of `i` in `main` since `operator-` gets its argument by value. You need to use:

   ```
   i = -i;
   ```

   to see the effect of calling the function.

Comment: Also, could I do it calling it by reference?

Comment: You could but it won't be idiomatic. When you use `j = -i;`, the value of `i` is not changed.

Answer (score 1):

This will work too:(Use reference)

```
#include<iostream>
//fifty6s
using namespace std;
class invert_position
{
    int x,y;
    public:
        invert_position(int a,int b)
        {
            x=a;
            y=b;
        }
    void show()
        {
            cout<<"\nx="<<x;
            cout<<"\ny="<<y;
        }
    friend void operator -(invert_position &);
};
void operator -(invert_position &i)
{
    i.x=-i.x;
    i.y=-i.y;
}
int main()
{
    invert_position i(2,3);
    -i;
    i.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
friend invert_position -(invert_position i)
{        
     i.x=-i.x;
     i.y=-i.y;
     i.z=-i.z;
     return i;
}
```

And in main function 
i=-i;
should be there because friend function is a non member function so it need to return the values... Thanks